# Add objects to status bar in iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there some new feature in the iOS SDK for adding stuff to the status bar in an iOS app?

I thought it wasn't allowed, but this app seems to do it:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/holtwick-it/id288374601?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's simply a custom view drawn above the status bar. IIRC this is how Reeder does it.